# using Lookup in VBA,Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have two Sheets , sheet1 and sheet2 .

Sheet1 has 27 columns, and sheet2 has 10 columns,

I am looking for the Id in sheet 1, column J and Need the corresponding date in sheet 2 , column g.

I Need this corresponding date to be printed in sheet 1 , column AA.

I am using the following belo VBA, it is printing the column D of sheet 2 insted of Column G.

This is the formula,

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(j2;sheet2!$A:$L;7;0);"")

I dont want to use, record macro functionality. Kindly, help me to correct the code.

```
 Sub lookup()

Dim totalrows As Long
Dim totalcolumn As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim i As Long

totalrows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To totalrows

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 10).Value)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then

Cells(i, 27).Value = rng.Value

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `rng.offset(0,x)` maybe?

Comment: why rng.Offset? i Need the date from column g. If i Need some other data, i think, i could used Offset.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I am still not sure, if it is pasting the corresponding data from column D. In this case, I guess i am missing some Key Point in the code.

Comment: Try limiting your find to the column `Sheets("Sheet2").columns("G").find` you are looking in, then use offset, if needed, it can exist anywhere in the sheet this way.

Comment: how do i do it  ? Sorry, for the direct question, i am new to vba

Comment: @Nathan_Sav there is an runtime error, Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

Comment: Instead of `Cells(i, 27).Value = rng.Value` try `Cells(i, 27).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rng.Row, 7)`.

Comment: You do seem to be giving it a minute or to  :) try doing some investigation.  It's your code, in front of you.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I am trying to investigate, Ist been 2 days i am struggling with this issue.

Comment: @Mrig The code is printing some values, which are not even in my sheet2. something like this 43006,7083333333 aslo, it just printed the heading plan date in someof the columns

Comment: `...and Need the corresponding date in sheet 2 , column g. I Need this corresponding date to be printed in sheet 1 , column AA` If I understood correctly, you want `Sheet 2 -> Column G` values in `Sheet 1-> Column AA` for corresponding IDs.

Comment: @Mrig ya , you understood it correctly. the ID are in column J of sheet 1.  Also, for reference, i have given the formula. I would like to have that in VBA. I dont want record macro Option.

Comment: `Cells(i, 27).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rng.Row, 7)` should work, is it possible for you to share sample/dummy data from your sheets.

Comment: @Mrig I can share, But how do i share it with you ?

Comment: You can upload it online and share the link here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147601/discussion-between-mikz-and-mrig).

Comment: This sort of issue is frequently due to not properly qualifying all of your ranges, worksheets, etc.  You should qualify every call to a range by the appropriate worksheet.  Avoid ActiveSheet, Select, Activate, etc when trying to access a cell.  And UsedRange can easily get out of sync with reality.  All of these topics are covered in various SO Q&A's.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Since, I could not figure it out, i posted. I am sorry, I Need Expertise Support to solve this. I refered them.i could not figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `FOR` loop you can use:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AA2:AA" & totalrows).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2:J15"), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("$A:$L"), 7, 0), "")
```

**EDIT:_____________________________________________________________________________**

```
Sub lookup()
    Dim totalrows As Long, totalrowsSht2 As Long
    totalrows = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    totalrowsSht2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AA2:AA" & totalrows).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2:J" & totalrowsSht2), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("$A:$L"), 7, 0), "")
End Sub
```